# Find Taylor series for $\sinh z$ about point $z_0=\pi i$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find Taylor series for $$\sinh z$$ about point $$z_0=\pi i$$
>   I know
>     $$\sinh \left ( z+\pi i \right )=-\sinh z$$
>   and that $\sinh z$ is periodic with period $2\pi i$. Now

$$\sinh(z)=z+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}+\frac{z^7}{7!}+......$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

> at $z=0$. But where to from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track.  Since $\sinh(z-i\pi)=-\sinh(z)$ we can write

$$\sinh(z)=-\sinh(\color{blue}{z-i\pi})=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\color{blue}{z-i\pi})^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$